# How to remove everything after a space in a column of an R data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a column that looks like:

```
date
12/04/33 12:34 24
12/03/22 12:43 26
11/01/24 11:22 42
```

I want to strip everything after the first space so that my column looks like:

```
date
12/04/33 
12/03/22
11/01/24
```

Does anyone know how to do this simply? Perhaps using `stringr`?

Answer (score 0):

```
data %>%
  mutate(
    stringr::str_remove(date, ' .*')
  )
```

or

```
data %>%
  mutate(
    stringr::word(date, 1)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! But oddly it is not working. The code runs but then when I `view(data)`, the column has not updated. Any ideas?

Comment: @CheckThis You need to assign the output of the above code to data with `-> data`. It seems that you have fundamental gaps in your knowledge of the R programming language and would benefit more from reading a tutorial. See the [R tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) for some great resources.